# AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'list' in Twitter streaming code

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter

I'm looking to replicate some code from an online course, but get the following error message after the last line of the code below:

**AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'list'**

I found a similar file in the author's GitHub: https://github.com/hugobowne/playing_with_twitter/blob/master/listening_to_tweets.py but it seems to be in v2.7 when I'm running 3.5 and is somewhat different from the course code. Can somebody comment on what might be going wrong with my code?

Thanks very much for your help.

```
# import packages
import tweepy
import json
import pandas as pd

# Store OAuth authentication credentials in relevant variables
# ...access_token etc all provided in my code

# Pass OAuth details to tweepy's OAuth handler
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def __init__(self, api=None):
        super(MyStreamListener, self).__init__()
        self.num_tweets = 0
        self.file = open("tweets.txt", "w")

    def on_status(self, status):
        tweet = status._json
        self.file.write(json.dumps(tweet) + '\n')
        tweet.list.append(status)
        self.num_tweets += 1
        if self.num_tweets < 100:
            return True
        else:
            return False
        self.file.close()

    def on_error(self, status):
            print(status)

            # Create Streaming object and authenticate
l = MyStreamListener()
stream = tweepy.Stream(auth, l)

# This line filters Twitter Streams to capture data by keywords:
stream.filter(track=['clinton','trump','sanders','cruz'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Change four things:

1. Add `self.tweets = []` to `__init__`
2. Change `tweet.list.append(status)` to `self.tweets.append(status)`
3. Delete `self.num_tweets += 1`
4. Change `if self.num_tweets < 100:` to `if len(self.tweets) < 100`

Comment: Hi Eric, Thanks very much for taking the time to reply. Very much appreciated and my apologies for the delay in following up. Would you mind just clarifying how to incorporate step 1 into the code? I have come across ___ init ___ before, but am not familiar enough with it just yet(adding to to-do list), so it's not immediately clear to me how to add it. Thanks very much again!